# How to get a share of Google's search revenue?

Tags: google, search, revenue

Mozilla gets money from Google when somebody searches in Google through Firefox and then clicks an ad.

If people search on your own website with Google, you also get a share if they click an ad in search results.

But is it possible to search the web with Google from your website and still get a share just like Mozilla does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) that you can create for your own site can be made to search the web in general (in fact, I think it's the default option).

However I believe Mozilla has a special deal with Google to use their search (which actually sends the user direct to Google, not to a proxy site). It's unlikely you would be able to do any similar deal unless you were getting a huge number of searches with your site.

Comment: Regarding Mozilla, it will be interesting to see how their [relationship with Bing](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/search/archive/2011/10/26/bff.aspx) works out...